# Limits of Kummer Confluent Hypergeometric function for fixed z

Tags: limits, hypergeometric-function

I have the following:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=0}^{\alpha_{2}}C\, e^{az}\, M(-\alpha_{2}+j,-\alpha_{3}+j,-\lambda z)\Bigg|_{z=-\infty}^{0}
\end{equation}

$C$ is a constant, $a,\alpha_{2},\alpha_{3}, \lambda$ are all positive.  Also, in my case, the arguments of $M$ give me a polynomial of degree $\alpha_{2}$.

How can I solve for the limits of $z\to -\infty$, and $z\to 0^{-}$?  I thought using the Kummer relation,

$M(a,b,z) = e^z\,M(b-a,b,-z)$

might simplify the expression but wasn't sure if it would help.  The answer seems obvious since I would think $e^x$ grows quicker than $x^n$ but I still dont know how to figure this one out.

Comment: Are you saying that the hypergeometric series gets truncated and becomes a polynomial? If yes, then you have $e^{az}\times$ a polynomial...

Comment: Pierpaolo Vivo, the answer is yes it does get truncated.  I end up with something that looks like $M(-a,-b,-cx)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}C_{j} \, x^{n-j}$.  I guess then your answer is the limit at negative infinity is zero?

Comment: I would say so. And for the limit at $0$, you only need the constant term of the polynomial.

Comment: Pierpaolo Vivo,  I agree with what you are saying for the limit at infinity.  I also see why it would seem that the limit at zero would give the constants of each term in the poly.  However, if I take the limit of just the hypergeometric function (which wolfram alpha allows me to do) I get

Comment: Pierpaolo Vivo,  I agree with what you are saying for the limit at infinity.  I also see why it would seem that the limit at zero would give the constants of each term in the poly.  However, if I take the limit of just the hypergeometric function (which wolfram alpha allows me to do) I get: $\lim_{x\to 0} M(-a,-b,-c*x) = 1$ regardless of the direction.  Even stranger is if I take the limit of $\lim_{x\to 0} e^{x}x^{a}=0$ which seems to contradict the previous result.  I might post this stuff in the question so that its all in one spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a bit of work it seems the answer was obvious.  The Kummer Confluent Hypergeometric function is defined as:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
{_{1}}F_{1}(a,b,z)&=\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_{s}}{(b)_{s}\,s!}\,z^{s}\\
&=1+\frac{a}{b}\,z+\frac{a(a+1)}{b(b+1)2!}\,z^{2}+\cdots
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

The question is based off a special case of this definition where the arguments result in a finite number of terms.  Regardless, if we carry to $e^{az}$ term inside the sum and take the limit of each term the result will be one.  This is because $\lim_{x\to 0} ax^{n}e^{bx}=0$, and for the first term we get $\lim_{x\to 0} e^{bx}=1$.